# Calculate the angle between two points over a period of time

Tags: python, math, angle, timedelta, coordinate-systems

I would like to calculate the angle between two points in a coordinate system over a period of time.

X: Time
Y: Values of a currency Pair.

**For example:**

At 10AM(X1) the pair was at 1.1110(Y1) Euros. At 11AM(X2) the pair was at 1.1190(Y2) Euros.

Now I would like to calculate the angle. Do I need to calculate the DeltaX like: Delta 1 hour = 60 min = DeltaX = 60?

Or do I need to convert the time to something else?

I tried it like this already but the outcome seems to be not right.

```
x1 = 0
x2 = 60
y1 = 1.1110
y2 = 1.1190

delta_y = ((y2)-(y1))**2
delta_x = ((x2)-(x1))**2
radian = math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x)
degree = radian*(180/math.pi)
print(degree)
```

Outcome:
0.0002291831180511074

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work and convert your values into the right angle in degree:

```
import math

x1 = 0
x2 = 60
y1 = 1.1110
y2 = 1.1190

#Calculate the length of the opposite and adjacent sides
delta_y = y2 - y1
delta_x = x2 - x1

# Calculate tangens
tan = delta_y / delta_x

# Calculate inverse function of tangens (arctan)
alpha_rad = math.atan(tan)

#Calculate alpha from rad to degree
alpha_degree = alpha_rad * (180/math.pi)

print(alpha_degree)
```

Comment: I think that the angle of the outcome is way too flat in your code. It shouldn't be 0.007639437223140244

Comment: This is because your values are very close to each other. If you try it with the slope calculator the results match my calculation. [link] (https://www.calculator.net/slope-calculator.html?type=1&x11=0&y11=1.1110&x12=60&y12=1.1190&x=74&y=17)

Comment: Alright. I might have found the mistake. I think i need to get the deltaY as 80 in this example instead of 0.0080 because in Forex the 4th decimal point is where you start to read the number... So it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: `delta_y` is in euros, `delta_x` is in minutes. What is `arctan(delta_y / delta_x)`'s unit??